# CakePHP displaying errors at top of page

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a CakePHP 2 app. I've been trying to workout how best to display my form errors at the top of the page. I've found a few other posts that have helped me get the errors but I'm struggling looping through them to display them properly.

My form consists of many rows of fields - each row is a separate db row (an individual expense as part of a expense claim).

I'm setting this in the controller to pass the errors :

```
$this->set('errors', $this->ExpenseClaim->validationErrors);
```

This is passing through this array of errors:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'date' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense date cannot be blank'
        ),
        'sitename' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense sitename cannot be blank'
        ),
        'detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense details cannot be blank'
        ),
        'amount' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense amount cannot be blank'
        ),
        'total' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense total should not be blank'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'date' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense date cannot be blank'
        ),
        'sitename' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense sitename cannot be blank'
        ),
        'detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense details cannot be blank'
        ),
        'amount' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense amount cannot be blank'
        ),
        'total' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'The expense total should not be blank'
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried lots of different foreach loops to try and get the errors out but am failing due to the level of nesting. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I just want an error like - "The expense date cannot be blank in row 1".

I'm using jQuery to insert rows so cant rely on the form helper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was over complicating things! Hopefully this may help someone else:

```
foreach ($errors['Expense'] as $key => $error) {
        foreach ($error as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $val) { ?>
                <li><?php echo $val; ?> in row <?php echo $key; ?></li>     
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```